# firestore crash runtimeException trying to get collection

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get collection from firestore .I am getting the following error .

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Firestore (0.6.6-dev).
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza.zzb(SourceFile:324)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zzd.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5834)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
     Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Only one thread may be created in an AsyncQueue.
        at com.google.a.a.a.a.zza.zza(SourceFile:2032)
        at com.google.a.a.a.a.zza.zza(SourceFile:2017)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.newThread(SourceFile:195)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:582)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:988)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.g.zza$zza.run(SourceFile:191)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:820)
```

and the code

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("username","password").addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                db.collection("mycollection").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

the firebase authentication is working fine but the code is crashing when i try to get the collection as shown below .Sometimes the code works fine and onComplete is called

```
db.collection("mycollection").get().addOnCompleteListener
```

Answer (score 1):

First, try to clear the data in the application manager on the device and run the app again. If it's not working in this way, try add the following lines of code to progauard rule:

```
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}
```

Comment: Try to add `-keep class io.grpc.** {*;}` to your proguard configuration. It should work. In my case, it worked. If not, please add your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: i reinstall the app ,it work now thx .it seems like it happens only when i am trying to debug the app

Comment: Did my answer helped you?

Comment: it is still not work but its only happening in debug mode